# How to increase the precision of AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Is there a way to have a boundary time observer fire at exactly 5555 milliseconds (and then pause the video at this point)?

I'm playing around with the following code:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("colorfulStreak", withExtension: "m4v")!
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
player.actionAtItemEnd = .None

playerLayer.player = player
viewForPlayerLayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

let boundaryTime = NSValue(CMTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(5555, 1000)), 10000))
print ("Assigned Boundary Time: \(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(5555, 1000)), 10000))")
let observer = player.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([boundaryTime], queue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), usingBlock: { [weak self] in
    print("prior \(CMTimeGetSeconds((self?.player.currentTime())!))")
    self?.player.pause()
    print("after \(CMTimeGetSeconds((self?.player.currentTime())!))")
})
effectTimeObserver = observer
```

The output of this varies with each run when the boundary observer fires:

Assigned Boundary Time: CMTime(value: 555500, timescale: 100000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)

-- Trial 1:

prior 5.555807083

after 5.555963386

--
Trial 2:

prior 5.555156239

after 5.555312723

---

Comment: Note, `let boundaryTime = NSValue(CMTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(5555, 1000)), 10000))` got a little messy as I was trying to convince the boundary observer to be more precise, but the same output results when just using the center-most CMTimeMake.